# google maps v3 not displaying all markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have 19 postal codes in an array which go through GeoCode, it seems to work fine but only 11 of them get displayed. I have searched and tried everything. I have only just started learning JavaScript and the map API, so I'm sure my spelling is wrong on something.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.378, -3.435); 

myOptions = {
 zoom: 5,
 center: latlng,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my_canvas"),myOptions);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var places = ["AB12 3AG","BS11 8AT","IG11 0HN","CA3 0PJ","NR19 1JG","IP11 3HZ","ML4 3LR","WF12 7TH","L33 7YE","M30 9QG","NG18 5DQ","MK12 5QL","PE6 0BN","ME10 3RL","SO40 9HN","B79 7TD","TS2 1RP","GU17 0NP","WV10 7EL"];

for(i = 0; i < places.length; i++){ 
 var address = places[i];
 geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, function(results){
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location,
      title: address
      });
 });
}
```

I think that all the post codes do load because the title for all the markers is the last address in the array 'WV10', but like I said, only 11 out of the 19 locations get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a function in a loop. At least this is the problem for the label. A solution for this is to create a new scope be calling a function inside the loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < places.length; i++){ 
 (function(place) {
     geocoder.geocode({'address':place}, function(results){
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             position: results[0].geometry.location,
             title: place
         });
     });
  }(places[i]));
}
```

This might also solve the display problem, but I'm not sure about this. Could it be that some places resolve to the same or very close positions?